# Uncaught Invalid Arguments jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Anyone can help me why I got this error?

```
Uncaught Invalid arguments jquery-ui.min.js:5 
$.extend.parseDate main.js:199 
$.datepicker.beforeShowDay jquery-ui.min.js:5 
$.extend._generateHTML jquery-ui.min.js:5 
$.extend._updateDatepicker jquery-ui.min.js:5 
$.extend._inlineDatepicker jquery-ui.min.js:5 
$.extend._attachDatepickerjquery-ui.min.js:5 
(anonymous function) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 
b.extend.each jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 
b.fn.b.each jquery-ui.min.js:5 
$.fn.datepicker main.js:194 
(anonymous function)jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 
c jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 
p.fireWithjquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 
b.extend.readyjquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
H
```

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function() {

  "use strict";

  $("#open_datepicker").datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      numberOfMonths: [1,2],
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#dateto").val());
        var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#datefrom").val());
        return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
      },
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#dateto").val());
        var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#datefrom").val());
                var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);


                if (!date1 || date2) {
          $("#datefrom").val(dateText);
          $("#dateto").val("");
                    $(this).datepicker();
                } else if( selectedDate < date1 ) {
                    $("#dateto").val( $("#datefrom").val() );
                    $("#datefrom").val( dateText );
                    $(this).datepicker();
                } else {
          $("#dateto").val(dateText);
                    $(this).datepicker();
        }
      }
    });

});
```

FYI, I use jQuery 1.9.1 and jQueryUI 1.9.2.
Actually I wanna make like thi http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk/. I see that fiddle is works, but mine is not.

Comment: usually best to use development version instead of minified so you can see where the error occurs in the source of plugin. My guess is you should check for values before passing them into parseDate

Comment: it was my fault. The input ID's didn't match with selector in js script above. Thank you for fast response.